# Menu bar flicker when goes to different page

Tags: php, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem on my flickering menu bar?

Please suggest anything that will make the flickering of menu bar stop.

Thanks much!

```css
#mainmenu{
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}
.menubar{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    max-height:10em;
    width:100%;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:#333333;
    text-align: left;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.menubar .first {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
.menubar li{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width:15em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-bottom: none;
    cursor: pointer;


}

.menubar li:hover{
        background-color:#6666ff;
}
.menubar a{
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffffff;
}



/* for submenus */

.menubar .first .submenubar {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:2em;
    left:0;
    width:auto;
    display: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 13px 25px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 13px 25px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 13px 25px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

.menubar li .submenubar li {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color:brown;
    display: block;
    color:#fff;  

}
.menubar > li > .submenubar > li:hover {
   background-color:black;
}
.menubar li:hover .submenubar{
    display: block;
}
```

See this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5bawhnt/) for my complete code.

Comment: No flickering - Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m. What browser you use, and when it flickers - on hover?

Comment: when i click on different page/menu .

Comment: Does the fiddle demonstrate the issue? I see no flickering here - Opera 28.0 .

Comment: Neither the question nor the fiddle has any jQuery, so why the jQuery tag?

Comment: i just think maybe query might solve the problem?

Comment: @shin - what browser are you using. I can only see an issue with z-index here, but I wouldn't call it a flickering

Comment: Dude - chrome Canary is fine too - Version 44.0.2377.0 canary (64-bit), if you're interested

Comment: google chrome 41.02 . yeah. i think flickering is not the right term. but reloading? im sorry.

Comment: hm - it doesn't happen in jsfiddle, is it happening outside of it - locally on your machine? Tell us more about, what you experience, as precisely as you can

Comment: thank you @robjez. i realized the problem is on my browser. I have tried it on firefox and it is okay. i does not flash when clicking on the menu bar. any idea what might solve the problem on google chrome?

Comment: no, not sure about it, but it happens only to you - it seems. Some glitch perhaps, try to reinstall the browser. Is it only happening on jsfiddle? Have you tested code outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that one of 2 things are happening.

1. Is the whole header "flickering" when you go to a new page? If so,
   that's because you are building an html page from your php on the
   server and then rendering the page again. Sometimes this will flash.
   Sucks.
2. The sub-menu appears to "flicker" because it's broken and when you
       try and hove over it, it disappears.

If it's 1, you can use caching to try and lessen the chances of this happening, or you can learn how to use ajax, or a js framework to build single page apps, but that's a lot of work.

If it's 2, then this code I'll include below, and [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/c5bawhnt/3/) - will set you up with some more solid code to work with.

My real advice, is to just never use drop-down menus. They are a terrible interface pattern.

### HTML

```
<nav class='container navigation'>
<div class='inner-w'>

    <ul class='menu'>
        <li>
            <a href='#'>Top-level menu item 1</a>
            <ul class='sub-menu'>
                <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Top-level menu item 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href='#'>Top-level menu item 3</a>
            <ul class='sub-menu'>
                <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Sub-menu item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Top-level menu item 4</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
</nav>
```

### CSS

```
/* global-structure */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.container .inner-w {
    margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 900px; /* arbitrary */
    /* this should have a clear-fix */
}

/* menu styles */
.menu, .menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
    float: left;
}

.menu > li { /* just the top-level li */
    position: relative;
    /* so the sub-menu can be positioned to this */
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}

.menu > li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: .8rem .5rem;
    background: #eee;
    min-width: 160px;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0; /* just hide it visually */
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5; /* arbitrary, keep them small though... */
}

.sub-menu li {
    clear: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}

.sub-menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-menu a {
    background: #ccc;
}

.sub-menu a:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}

.menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

If I was absolutely forced to write a drop-down menu, It would have to be like this:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/qdBryb/?editors=010